# I can't install libopenblas via yum on Centos 7

Tags: linux, repository, centos7, yum, openblas

Hello Stackoverflow user,

I want to compile NWChem program on CentOS 7 and it requires an OpenBlas library. I have tried to install the OpenBlas via yum installer using command: `yum -y install libopenblas` or `yum -y install libopenblas-devel`.

Unluckily, it did not work and the error message is like there is no the openblas library in the repository.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure, but the correct package name should be `openblas-devel.x86_64`. Try the command `yum install openblas-devel.x86_64 -y`.

Comment: It's not work either.

Comment: Please try to add epel repo. Commands are below.

Comment: wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm

Comment: Thanks so much. I've done it.

Comment: My Pleasure. Glad i could help.